# what is difference between ++i and i+=1 from any point of view

Tags: c, operators

This is a question from kn king's c programming : a modern approach. I can't understand the solution given by him:-

```
The expression ++i is equivalent to (i += 1). The value of both expressions is i after 
the increment has been performed.
```

How do I understand this anyway?

Comment: What part of it do you not understand?

Comment: And suppose if `i = 10` then after `i += 1`, `i` becomes `11`.

Comment: You’re wrong in the point that `++i` ≠ `i++`, and I’m gonna give an example.

Comment: @skp: Do you see "i++" anywhere in the question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
i = 10
printf("%d", i++);
```

will print 10, where as

```
printf("%d", ++i);
```

will print 11

`X = i++` can be thought as this

```
X = i
i = i + 1
```

where as `X = ++i` is

```
i = i + 1
X = i
```

so,

```
printf ("%d", ++i);
```

is same as

```
printf ("%d", i += 1);
```

but not

```
printf ("%d", i++);
```

although value of `i` after any of these three statements will be the same.

Answer (score 5):

The solution means to say that there *is* no difference, `++i` has the same meaning as `(i += 1)` no matter what `i` happens to be and no matter the context of the expression. The parentheses around `i += 1` make sure that the equivalence holds even when the context contains further arithmetics, such as `++i * 3` being equivalent to `(i += 1) * 3`, but not to `i += 1 * 3` (which is equivalent to `i += 3`).

The same would not apply to `i++`, which has the same side effect (incrementing `i`), but a different value in the surrounding expression — the value of `i` before being incremented.

Comment: However `i++ + 1` is always equivalent to `++i` and `i+=1`. :-)

Comment: The operator signature is identical. They both return e.g. int&.

Comment: @user2672165: There is no such thing as `int&` in C.

Comment: There are indeed no reference types in C, but that expression will return an `int` typed L-value whose storage is named by the variable `i`.

Comment: @Novelocrat No. `++i` and `i++` are not lvalues in C. You may be thinking of C++ again. The C standard is not great at clearly defining lvalues, so I won't provide a reference, but ask any C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

`++i` is the pre-increment operator. It increments `i` before setting and returning the value (which is obviously `i + 1`).

Now, `i++` is the post-increment operator. It increments `i` after the whole instruction it appears in is evaluated.

Example:

```
int i = 0;
std::cout << ++i << std::endl; /* you get 1 here */
std::cout << i++ << std::endl; /* you still get 1 here */
std::cout << i << std::endl;   /* you get 2 here */
```

Comment: Question is tagged `C`, not `C++`.

Comment: And the question does not involve postincrement.

Comment: More importantly, the words “before” and “after” in this answer do not reflect the reality of pre- and post-increment in C (and probably not in C++ either). `i++` evaluates to the last value of `i` and increments `i` at any time between the last and the next sequence point, and the program is not allowed to try to observe when.

Answer (score 1):

One difference that has not been brought up so far is readability of code. A large part of loops use increment by one and common practice is to use i++/++i when moving to the next element / incrementing an index by 1.

Typically i+= is used in these cases only when the increment is something other than 1. Using this for the normal increment will not be dangerous but cause a slight bump in the understanding and make the code look unusual.

Answer (score 1):

**Difference between both are:** ++ is a unary operator while + is a binary operator....
**If we consider execution time:** `i++ is more faster than i=i+1.`
No of machine cycles differs to execute the same set of code, thats the reason ++ operators are always prefered for Loops.
[Refer to this thread for more info](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080722061409AAxRnHv)

Answer (score 0):

I think they are totally the same. There is one thing maybe interesting. The ++i is equal to (i+=1) but not i+=1; The difference is the brace. Because i += 1 may depend on the context and it will have different interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

In a normal operation without assignation:

++i and i++

increase the variable in 1. In pseudo assembly both code it is:

```
inc i
```

but If you assign the value the order of ++ is relevant:

x = i++

produce:

```
mov x, i
inc i
```

x = ++i

produce:

```
inc i
mov x, i
```

In the case of:
i += 1

it will produce:

```
add i,1
```

but because compilers optimize the code it also will produce in this case:

```
inc i
```