# Whats the difference between ++i and i+1 in javascript

Tags: javascript, indexof

how can this give me different results?

The only difference is the [++i] and [i+1]

```
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
  total = inputArray[0] * inputArray[1];

  for (i = 1; i < inputArray.length-1; i++) {
    mul = inputArray[i] * inputArray[++i];
    if (total < mul)
      total = mul;
      }
  return total;
}

    function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
  total = inputArray[0] * inputArray[1];

  for (i = 1; i < inputArray.length-1; i++) {
    mul = inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1];
    if (total < mul)
      total = mul;
      }
  return total;
}
```

Thanks for helping.

This question was marked as duplicate but the other questions are about i++ and mine is about ++i.

Comment: For example if you call the function with:

adjacentElementsProduct([3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]);

Comment: `++i` has a side effect which `i+1` does not have. That should be enough of a hint.

Answer (score 1):

`++i` increments `i` by one and saves new value into `i`

`i+1` increments current value in `i` by one, but doesn't save new value into `i`

also check this question
[what is difference between ++i and i+=1 from any point of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420479/what-is-difference-between-i-and-i-1-from-any-point-of-view)

Comment: Thank you very much