# Are ++i, i = i + 1 and i += 1 equivalent in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, memory, variable-assignment, increment

My actual concern is about whether the expressions of `++i;`, `i = i + 1;`  and `i += 1;` are one-hundred percent equivalent to each other, if `i` is defined before.

1. `++i;` - `i` gets immediately incremented by `1` within the statement, as opposed to `i++;` where the incremetation by `1` is done after the expression.
2. `i = i + 1;` - `i` gets immediately incremented by `1` within the statement.
3. `i += 1;` - `i` gets immediately incremented by `1` within the statement.

Are there *any kind of differences between those expressions or are they 100% equivalent?

*"Any" may refer to syntax and semantics, but also to performance and memory-management.

Comment: They are not equivalent for non-fundamental types..

Comment: A minor correction: in `i++` `i` is also immediately incremented by 1, however the expression returns a temporary with the previous value of `i`.

Comment: C or C++? The answers will differ.

Comment: @exnihilo, that comment deserves an answer explaining both.

Comment: @exnihilo I wanted to ask for both because I did not see a difference and would like to use the respective statements with both languages, if it is possible.

Comment: @Andreas-he-her- That gives an answer to the C++ part of using `++i`. Thank you very much for it. But what about the comparison between `i = i + 1;` and `i += 1;` in C++ and the C part of the question?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio The definitions of their respective implementations is equal in both languages, but the rules of compiler may be different.

Comment: Is your question specific to native c++ type int? Take a look here https://godbolt.org/z/cAH5wf

Comment: @Andreas-he-her- Do you mean that `i = i + 1;` and `i += 1;` are equivalent in C and C++? But what about the comparison of `i = i + 1;`, `i += 1;` and `++i` in C? BTW, do you got any reference that `i = i + 1;` and `i += 1;` are equivalent in C and C++?

Comment: @EyalD Well, yes, consider `i` as of type `int` or any other integer-compatible type. If there are to the context relevant differences between the multiple integer types, I would be glad if you can point them.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Wikipedia has a limited description: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18420558/5229664 they are the same! And it's logical to be same in performance or memory-management because all of them have to go through a same path to compute in memory!

Comment: @Dialecticus Ok, Thank you for the hint but are they equivalent for fundamental types?

Comment: You can check for yourself: https://godbolt.org/z/5aqmnH

Comment: @FarbodAhmadian Ok, thank you for the link. But still keeps the question if `i = i + 1` is equivalent to `i += 1` and `++i` in C in any kind of the mentioned topics.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I don't know of a difference between built-in- numerical types (might be), but note that for classes you can overload the operators to do whatever you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### C

In C, `i = i+1` and `i += 1` are not equivalent if `i` is an atomic type, because the compound assignment is a read-modify-write operation with `memory_order_seq_cst` semantics, per C 2018 6.5.16.2 3. I also cannot say the C standard is completely clear on the semantics of `i = i+1` and `i += 1` in regard to volatile objects. Otherwise, `++i`, `i = i+1`, and `i += 1` are equivalent, given that `i` is merely an identifier, not a placeholder for any more complicated expression.

#### C++

In C++, the operations are not equivalent. Proof:

This program:

```
#include <iostream>


class SensitiveToOperations
{
public:
    SensitiveToOperations operator ++() { std::cout << "Preincrement.\n"; return *this; }
    SensitiveToOperations operator +(int that) const { std::cout << "Addition.\n"; return *this; }
    SensitiveToOperations operator =(SensitiveToOperations that) { std::cout << "Assignment.\n"; return *this; }
    SensitiveToOperations operator +=(int that) { std::cout << "AdditionAssignment.\n"; return *this; }
};


int main(void)
{
    SensitiveToOperations i;
    ++i;
    i = i + 1;
    i += 1;
}
```

produces this output:

```
Preincrement.
Addition.
Assignment.
AdditionAssignment.
```

thus showing that different results may be obtained for the different operations.

For fundamental types, the operations may be largely equivalent, but I am not qualified to speak to C++ semantics with regard to atomic or volatile.

Comment: The canonical implementation of increment and decrement operators for integer types, is the use of assignment and addition/subtraction, thus we assume `x = ++i` is equal to `i = i + 1; x = i`. The use of `i` further implies an integer type, but I guess there are some uses for overriding these operators with different behaviour. Hope I won't encounter such custom behaviour on integers, though.

Answer (score 4):

In C, `++i` is equivalent to `(i += 1)`

[C11 Draft Standard 6.5.3.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.1p2):

> The expression ++E is equivalent to (E+=1).

The expression `i += 1` is equivalent to `i = i + 1`, *except* that in the first case `i` is guaranteed to be evaluated only one time. In function calls `i += 1` results in a single evaluation.

[C11 Draft Standard 6.5.16.2p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.2p3):

> A compound assignment of the form E1 op = E2 is equivalent to the
>   simple assignment expression E1 = E1 op (E2), except that the lvalue
>   E1 is evaluated only once, and with respect to an
>   indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of a compound
>   assignment is a single evaluation. If E1 has an atomic type, compound
>   assignment is a read-modify-write operation with memory_order_seq_cst
>   memory order semantics.

You might expect performance to be marginally better for `++i`, given that `i` is evaluated only once in this expression, but this really comes down to implementation details and how well your compiler optimizes. Performance and memory-management issues are outside of the purview of the [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag.